# проблема с LWIP на stm32

Tags: stm32, ethernet

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь освоить работу с Ethernet на stm32. Причём без всяких внешних SPI подключаемых микросхем. Использую плату Nucleo с установленным на ней камешком STM32F767ZIT. Для написания программ использую широкоиспользуемую новичками связку CubeMX и Keil uVision 5. Проблема начинаются почти с самого начала.[image: Инициализация в CubeMX] Включаю в кубе CAN, UART, Ethernet, настраиваю тактирование, саму библиотеку LWIP не забываю подключить. Собираю проект. Открываю кеил и собираю проект уже там. Но не тут то было. Кеил выдает такие странные ошибки.

```
767-2\767-2.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol sio_open (referred from slipif.o).
767-2\767-2.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol sio_send (referred from slipif.o).
767-2\767-2.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol sio_tryread (referred from slipif.o).
```

Как я понимаю дело в том, что не подключились какие то файлы из библиотеки LWIP. Но вот дело в том, что то же самое я попробовал на другом камешке, а именно STM32f107RC и там закомпилился начальный проект без проблем. Хотя, насколько я понимаю, файлы подлючаются одни и те же. Вопрос: как оживить ethernet вместе с LWIP на stm32f767zit?

Comment: Если вы в своём проекте не используете протокол SLIP (Serial Line IP), то удалите из проекта его реализацию (`LwIP\src\include\netif\slipif.h` и `LwIP\src\netif\slipif.c`). Как это сделать, я к сожалению не подскажу, поскольку не использую Keil uVision. Если используете, то вам самому придется для STM32 реализовать все функции, объявленные в заголовочном файле `LwIP\src\include\lwip\sio.h`, поскольку st-ники такую реализацию в STM32Cube не сделали.

Comment: Что касается STM32F1, то там используется более древняя версия lwIP, в которой протокол SLIP по умолчанию отключен. Это настраивается через `#define LWIP_HAVE_SLIPIF` в заголовочном файле `src\include\lwip\opt.h`. В реализации STM32Cube для STM32F7 идет новая версия lwIP, в которой данная настройка отсутствует.

Comment: У этого контроллера есть встроенный PHY? Обычно подключение внешней микросхемы всё-таки требуется, и работают они по интерфейсу MII или RMII. Я не вижу у вас этого интерфейса.

Comment: Спсибо большое за ответы. Я просто в Keil удалил из проекта файлы slipif.c и slipif.h и программа, по крайней мере, закомпилилась. Что касается встренного PHY, то он одназначно есть, а конкретноя  использую RMII. Думаю, у меня ещё появится вопрос с связанный с работой с ETHERNET на stm32 и, если вы не против, я бы их задал на этой странице.

Comment: @Nowsan, лучше создать новый вопрос.